# ionic cloud push notification : Transit to specific state when app is closed/background using

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic-cloud

I have successfully set $ionicPush (ionic cloud) notification, and I'm able to receive push notification successfully on android device.

But when my android app is closed/background what i would like to do is   when I click on received notification in notification area, I want to transit to specific state based on notification param/payload.

I'm passing message by FCM dashboard with

```
payload : {"$state":"stateName"}
```

Below is my code for receiving notifications

```
$rootScope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, notification) {    
        var state=notification.message.payload.$state;
        console.log("State:" + state);
        if (typeof state != 'undefined') {
            window.localStorage.setItem('goafterpush',state);
        }
    });
```

But this above listener is not called when I clicked on received notification.

Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue, as I have already spent 2 days to solve it.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me on this ?